# Python Turtle library methods not working

Tags: python, python-turtle

Trying to create a basic snake game and it won't change the colour of the screen or create a turtle object. I've tried using different ways to input color etc, not working. I'm stumped, seems like things should be pretty straightforward at this level. Here's the code:

#Write your code below this line 
input('Player name: ')

```
import turtle as t

screen=t.Screen()
screen.title('WELCOME')
screen.bgcolor('black')

turtle_obj= t.Turtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the `screen.exitonclick()` to the last line of the code, everything works as you would expect.

This is because `exitonclick()` binds turtle's bye() method (which shuts the window) to wait for a click instead of just shutting down. It is effectively ending your program, but just waiting for a mouse click to do it.

Comment: Still not working!